# Confusion integrating react-native-firebase with Expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

I'm new to React Native development, and I'm making a development environment for a cross-platform app I'm building with Expo and Firebase.

I'm trying to integrate react-native-firebase with Expo because it's the only way I can use Firebase's 'App Check' functionality. I want a managed workflow where I'm not having to touch native code and am using the EAS development build.

I've tried to set up my environment using the following [article](https://bartlomiej-klocek.medium.com/how-to-integrate-react-native-firebase-into-expo-d34712eaf64d), but it's left me confused about something - **how do I connect my app to firebase? Do I use the standard web JS SDK, or is there something else I should be using?**

I've looked at the react-native-firebase [docs](https://rnfirebase.io/#expo) concerning the expo, which hasn't helped.

What's also confusing is this:  when I was trying to add firebase to my android app on the firebase console, it mentioned adding the firebase SDK to a build.gradle file - something which my project doesn't have. So have a missed a step in my setup?

If it's any help, here are the steps I've taken for my project so far:

```
1.) Created app with npx create-expo-app

2.) npm install -g eas-cli

3.) npx expo install expo-dev-client

 eas build 

4.) npx install @react-native-firebase/app

5.) Set up a project on firebase. Download google-services.json and GoogleService-Info.plist, and add them to the root of my expo project

6.) Configure app.json as follows:

    "ios": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.******.testapp"
    },
    "android": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.******.testapp"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [ "@react-native-firebase/app"],
```

Answer (score 1):

Gradle is a build tool commonly used for mobile application projects. However as you are using Expo, Expo is your build tool rather than Gradle.

In your `app.json` file, you can see that the configuration there mentions `./GoogleService-Info.plist` and `./google-services.json`. These are the configuration files produced by the Firebase Console once you register your [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#register-app) and [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#register-app) applications.

They can be redownloaded following [these directions](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592).

> 1. Go to your [Project settings](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/general/) in the Firebase console.
> 2. In the **Your apps** card, select the bundle ID/package name of the app for which you need a config file.
> 3. Click the download link for `GoogleService-Info.plist` or `google-services.json` (as appropriate).
> 4. Save the file to the root of your project, making sure that you only have the most recent downloaded config file.